# How and why and what for do tombstone records appear in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Studying kafka, came across issues `deletes tombstone messages` ( e.g. while log compaction)

But my question is: how do tombstones even appear there? Who and why wanna use it and for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are written by the producing application (e.g. Producer API, or Kafka Connect source connector) by putting a null in the value part of the message. It denotes a logical deletion for the associated key in the message.
If you use log compaction then in time the previous values for that key are actually deleted too.

More info: https://medium.com/@damienthomlutz/deleting-records-in-kafka-aka-tombstones-651114655a16

Comment: but why they are so eager to delete tombstones? it costs nothing but logically make sense. What if consumer haven't read it yet?

Comment: What if consumer haven't read it yet?  -> I think  this can be handled by configuring  the log compaction strategy accordingly using `delete.retention.ms` to make sure the consumer has read the messages by then.